# What is the best design of database tables when an entitiy has some records that are referencing other records in the same table?

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a small database that represent a small community of people, columns in the main table would be something like `ID`, `Full_Name`, `birth_Date`, `Address`, etc..

In terms of relationships (single or married) I have the three possibilities:

- A person may be a single (*say that we refer to this by a field holding the value 0*).
- A person may in relationship, but out side this community (*say that we refer to this by a field holding the value 1*).
- A person may in relationship to someone inside this community (*we refer by 1, but we need a reference to the second person { = his ID} to be to retrieve his data*).

What would be the best practical design of such problem?

**This design**:

`Person (ID, Name, Birth_Date, is_Married, Partner_ID)`

- Single: `Partner_ID = 0`
- Married to outsider: `Partner_ID =1`
- Else: (married inside the community): `Partner_ID` will refer to another
     record in the same table.

**Or This**:

```
Person (ID, Name, Birth_Date, Relationship_ID)

Relationships (ID, Person_ID, Partner_ID)
```

- Single: `Person.Relationship_ID = 0`
- Married to outsider: `Person.Relationship_ID <> 0` as well as `Relationships.Partner_ID = 0`
- Else (married inside the community): `Person.Relationship_ID <> 0` as well as `Relationships.Partner_ID <> 0`

Comment: You could add 2 dummy records in the table with the values 0 for single and 1 for married an  outsider, and then have a foreign key constraint referencing the id column.

Comment: If you wrote what you don't understand, I could...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a huge and very well mentioned project, then the second one will be recommended (Second one is the right method and it meets all normalization laws, Need to make a small change, Remove `RelationShip_ID` from First Table). The field `Person_ID` will connect both tables

Otherwise you can use the first scenario (Put allow null to `Partner_ID`). Lot of live projects are using the first option so don't worry.

Comment: In scenario #2, Do you think that it is possiple to remove `Person_ID` from `Relationship` table to become like this: `Relationships (ID, Partner_ID)`, where `ID` is a `PK` and `Partner_ID` is a `FK` referencing a record in the main tabel (named `Person`). @jishnukm ?

Comment: no its not possible. Table 1 `Person (ID, Name, Birth_Date)
` Table 2 `Relationships (ID, Person_ID, Partner_ID)` Here IDs are PK, Person_ID is FK.. du u get me?

Comment: i mean keeping `Person.Relationship_ID` and removing `Relationships.Person ID`, they would become : 1st table `Person (ID, Name, Birth_Date, Relationship_ID)` , and so on the second table would  be like this  : `Relationships (ID, Partner_ID)` @jishnukm ?